# Runtime exception when uploading file using vue.js and asp.net web api?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api, vuejs2, asp.net-web-api2

I've got an exception when I tried to upload an image file with something like this

> "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpFileCollection' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'."

I didn't use submit button, I just want to upload the file asynchronously without any postback.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="button" ref="upload" name="upload" v-on:click="UploadPhoto" />
```

**Vue.JS:**

```
             async UploadPhoto() {
                 let image = new FormData();
                image.append('name', 'fileUploader');
                image.append('file', this.$refs.fileUploader.files[0]);

                let config = {
                    headers: {
                      //  'Content-Type': 'image/*'
                       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                };

                // call server upload request here...
                let testRes = await axios.post('http://localhost:44347/api/GetUser/UploadPhoto', image, config).then()
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
                 this.result = testRes;
                 console.log(image);
            },
```

**Web Api:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/GetUser/UploadPhoto")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadPhoto([FromBody] HttpFileCollection selectedfiles)
{
 await Task.Run(() =>
            {
   string sPath= HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Dummy/");
             //   HttpFileCollection selectedfiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                 selectedfiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                HttpPostedFile file = selectedfiles[0];
                string fileName = new FileInfo(file.FileName).Name;

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Guid guid = new Guid();
                    string modFilename = guid.ToString() + "_" + fileName;
                    file.SaveAs(sPath + Path.GetFileName(modFilename));
                }
             });

            return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with HttpFileCollection. I am not sure what version of asp.net you are using since you didn't specify, but I suggest trying [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-3.0):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadPhoto(IFormFile file)
```

In case you want to have multiple file uploads, simply use:

```
List<IFormFile> yourKeyNameFromFormData
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion but I'm not using .net core. Would it still work if I'm still using a lower version of asp.net web api?

Comment: Do I need to use form submission on this on my template?